# allow remote mysql access on centos

Tags: mysql, centos, vps

I am relatively new at using linux and was wondering how hard it would be to allow remote access to mysql on my vps and if it is worth me doing for my needs.

The reason that I am asking is that I would like to use a desktop application to manage my databases instead of having to login to phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best way would be keep 3306 closed from the public and then use an ssh tunnel to connection to your mysql server.

here is an example using putty.

http://realprogrammers.com/how_to/set_up_an_ssh_tunnel_with_putty.html

Answer (score 1):

You can allow external connections from certain IP using this SQL command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO username@'IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

But please make sure you have

```
skip-networking
```

commented in your /etc/my.cnf